# Firebase cannot retrieve data from database "db.collection is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Cannot get anything from the firebase database. It is showing an error of:

`Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function`

I have the script setup here as shown:

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "*****",
  authDomain: "*****",
  databaseURL: "*****",
  projectId: "*****",
  storageBucket: "*****",
  messagingSenderId: "*****"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.database();

const firstName = document.querySelector('#firstName').value;
const mainButton = document.querySelector('#mainButton');

mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  db.collection("users").doc().set({
      first: firstName,
  })
  .then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="firstName" type="text" name="first-name" required>
<button id="mainButton" type="button">Submit</button>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change this:

```
const db = firebase.database();
```

into this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Since you are using firestore and not realtime database.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize

Comment: This is correct. I was also a missing one more reference script

Answer (score 1):

```
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const userRef = doc(db, "users");
setDoc(userRef, {
                first: firstName,
            });
```

By the way:

```
const paymentRef = doc(db, collection, user?.uid, "subcollection", paymentIntent.id);
            setDoc(paymentRef, {
                basket: basket,
                amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                created:    paymentIntent.created
            });
```

That's how you can refer doc and set or create. If it's not exist firebase will create...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
// import from firestore    
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";

// initialize the db
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

// access the db collection
const getFirestoreData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid, "favorites"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.data())); // log each doc
}
```