# React Native and Firebase: Retrieving documents from a database not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am trying to do what should be the simplest thing in the world: retrieve documents from my firebase database, but it's proving impossible. I am using React Native and Expo.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// ... React component

useEffect(() => {
  firebase.database().collection("users")
  .where("geohash", ">=", lower)
  .where("geohash", "<=", upper)
  .get()
  .then((docs) => console.log(docs));
}, []);
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
firebase.database().collection is not a function.
```

**What I have tried so far**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999540/firebase-cannot-retrieve-data-from-database-db-collection-is-not-a-function) says to change `firebase.database()` to `firebase.firestore()`, however, not only did this not work for me but I also use `firebase.database().ref("/users/" + uid).set()` and `firebase.database()ref("/users/" + uid).update()` in other parts of my app without a problem, so I don't think I should change it to `firebase.firestore()`. And when I did change it it throws an error anyway:

`Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project test-app8768 does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=test-app8768 to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

My Internet connection is perfectly fine.

**My question**

Anyway, my questions is simple: In a React Native App using Expo, how can I retrieve documents from a database using firebase?

It seems like either I'm misusing the syntax or I'm missing a library (although I'm using the same library that's allowing me to `update` and `set`, so I'd assume `get`ting documents should be in that same library too). Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase contains two databases:

- the Realtime Database, which stores data as a single JSON tree, and
- Cloud Firestore, which stores data in documents and collections.

The APIs of these databases are complete separate, so you can't use the API from one on the other database.

If you're using the Realtime Database, you access it from JavaScript through `firebase.database()`, and a location in that database with `ref("...").child("...")`.

If you're using Cloud Firestore, you access it from JavaScript using `firebase.firestore()`, and a document with `collection("...").doc("...")`.

Your code is mixing these APIs, which won't work. To access a document, you'd need something like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users")
  .where("geohash", ">=", lower)
  .where("geohash", "<=", upper)
  .get()
  .then((docs) => console.log(docs));
```

Which *will* get rid of the `firebase.database().collection is not a function.` message.

I recommend taking the time to read the documentation on [getting started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) with Firestore, as it'll prevent you from hitting many similar problems going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does this mean that if I have data saved in a Realtime Database that I want to also have access to in a fashion that I reference in my question, that I should save it in both the Realtime database and the Firestore?

Comment: Seems this is the case. I'll have to slightly rearrange my data structure. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.