# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: db.collection is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

code in which the error occurs:

```
const countRef = db.collection('counter').doc('counter');
const increment = firebase.Firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
const decrement = firebase.Firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
function change(num) {
    if (num>0) {
        countRef.update({ counter: increment });
    } else if (num<0) {
        countRef.update({ counter: decrement });
    };
};
```

The error is in the first line of code. I have also tried to search the internet for answers, but I have not yet found any.

Comment: What is `db`? Why do you think it should it have a `collection` method?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:google-cloud-firestore] so https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999600/19068 is probably a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960910/13130697 if you are using v9 of Firebase SDK

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>As you haven't shown what `db` is defined to, this answer may be incorrect/not help.</sub>

---

The issue seems to be that you are setting `db` to an object which doesn't have `collection()`.

Make sure that the `db` variable is defined and set to the following:

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

This object has the `collection()` method defined in it, which may fix the issue.